# Jpa custom findBy method enum value conversion

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following enum used by a JPA Entity :

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
enum Status {
  ACTIVE("Active"),
  INACTIVE("Inactive");

  final String activeStatus;

  public String getStatus() { return activeStatus; }
}
```

It has an AttributeConverter which converts to a String when I write to the DB and the works in the other direction as well so the value of `activeStatus` is persisted and the String value e.g. "Inactive" is turned into the correct enum instance Status.INACTIVE.

The trouble I'm having is that my custom findBy method doesn't find anything :

```
List<Entity> findByStatus(Status status);
```

This seems to be because the generated query is using the string "ACTIVE" and not using the converter.  I could just use the string value, but it seems like I must be missing how to do this ?  I tried adding an @Convert annotation specifying the converter to my findBy method :

```
@Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class)
List<Entity> findByStatus(Status status);
```

but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Please add your **full `StatusConverter`** implementation (with full I mean including the imports and package declaration). Specify which Spring Data version you are using (or Spring Boot and provide the dependencies) and if possible add your entity as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was because I didn't use @Convert on the column definition.